# Failed to find compatible Java Version, Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, compatibility, java-11, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently trying to install jenkins but i'm having issues with Java version. It is saying it failed to find compatibility java version. When it's correct. (image below) [image]

I've also check what java version i have, using the command line. Image is below. I don't understand why the SE Runtime is 18.9 when i specifically downloaded JDK kit 11

[image]

This is not a duplicate question. The other questions did not have this specific issue.

Comment: Your Java Home appears to be set wrongly. It should be the jdk-11.0.17 Folder. Try to set it manually in the installation process. Dont get confused by the Runtime Environment or the Hotspot Server. The Build is 11.0.17

Comment: I've changed it to say "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17" but i'm still getting the same issue

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling your current Java Version. Then do a reboot of your PC/Server followed by the installation of the JDK. Maybe use a JDK from Adoptium or Azul, which I can confirm is working. In case of Adoptium you can let the installer set the Java_Home Variable for you.

Comment: We are successfully using [Adoptium JRE 11 x64](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11) with Jenkins LTS version. I don't use the installer, I just extract the JRE from the ZIP to "C:\Program Files\Java", set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to this directory (**not** the "bin" sub dir) and add the path of the "bin" sub directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Try "C\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.-1.17" not "C\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.-1.17\bin\"

Answer (score 5):

Select the correct location of Java version as asked in the setup prompt.

Like : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding like that :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin

so, you need to remove bin in your path then its works

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17